# Customize DevExpress export to Excel

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, devexpress

I need to add additional row before the exported table:

```
| column1 | column2 |
| value   | value   |
```

and i need to export in a such way:

```
| date: 20.21.23 | date: 22.11.14 |
| column1        | column2        |
| value          | value          |
```

These date values are stored in my viewmodel and the best solution for me is to add these cells to a gridcontrol view, that visible only for printing.
I'm not sure is that possible.

At the moment i'm printing in a such way:

```
var link = new PrintableControlLink(Grid.View as IPrintableControl);
link.PrintingSystem.ExportOptions.Xlsx.TextExportMode = TextExportMode.Text;
link.CreateDocument(false);
link.ExportToXls(ms);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to defined data template for a gridcontrol:

```
<dxg:GridControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding Path=Content.ViewModelProp1, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding Path=Content.ViewModelProp2, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</dxg:GridControl.Resources>
```

In your handler you need to use a such code:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
var link = new PrintableControlLink(Grid.View as IPrintableControl);
link.PrintingSystem.ExportOptions.Xlsx.TextExportMode = TextExportMode.Text;
link.PageHeaderData = DataContext; //viewmodel instance
link.PageHeaderTemplate = (DataTemplate)Grid.Resources["HeaderTemplate"];
link.CreateDocument(false);
link.ExportToXls(ms);
```

I'd like to highlight that to access *DataContext* from your template you need to use *Content* property (e.g. *Content.ViewModelProp2*). In other way it will try to access RowContent model property.